Flutter : !debugLocked is not true
I have a problem when I write the following code
I write code and put (navigator.pop) But it shows this error :
This is the page I want to return to and :
import 'package:electrical_app/constans.dart';
import 'package:electrical_app/models/product.dart';
import 'package:electrical_app/screens/details_screen.dart';
import 'package:electrical_app/widgets/home/product_cart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeBody({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        bottom: false,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: kDefaultPadding / 2),
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 70),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: kBackgroundColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(40),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: products.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => ProductCard(
                      itemIndex: index,
                      product: products[index],
                      press: (){
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(
                              product: products[index],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}


This is the current page that I want to return from
import 'package:electrical_app/constans.dart';
import 'package:electrical_app/models/product.dart';
import 'package:electrical_app/widgets/details/details_body.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;

  const DetailsScreen({super.key, required this.product});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
      appBar: detailsAppBar(context),
      body: DetailsBody(
        product: product,
      ),
    );
  }

  AppBar detailsAppBar(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
      leading: IconButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: kDefaultPadding),
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back,
          color: kPrimaryColor,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
      centerTitle: false,
      title: Text(
        'رجوع',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
      ),
    );
  }
}


This is the error text :
════════ exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════ 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': failed assertion: line 5529 pos 12: '!_debuglocked': is not true

How do I solve this error?  and Thank you all [^o^]
I've seen some solutions here that say to put (navigation.push) in setState(){}
But this method did not work

Does this answer your question? Error thrown on navigator pop until : "!_debugLocked': is not true."

It means when you are clicking the back arrow btn in app bar, more then one call for pop is done. Can you try removing the Naviagtor.pop . You know right even if you not put this custom arrow for back btn. Flutter automatically does for you, if you use Appbar. I think with your own call, flutter is also calling Naviagtor.pop() for onClick on leading widget in Appbar. I think it will work of you just remove it
